# Run Windows Batch from SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I want to run batch file through SQL server. I have used command 
`EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'd:\abc.bat'`
but Query doesn't stop Execution without execution batch file.

Comment: Check SQL account permissions, use *.cmd files, not *.bat ones. What means "query doesn't stop execution"?

Comment: query doesn't stop running

Comment: Why should it? Do you mean that shell command will be executed, but sql script doesn't wait for finishing that execution? If you run your bat/cmd file from command window, does it wait or not?

Comment: batch file is running when i run it from command windows

Comment: Does it run, if you execute it from SSMS (management studio) query window? Just single line with `xp_cmdshell`, not entire query.

Comment: yes its working. and it is enabled also

Comment: but when i gave file name which is not exists it shows output in sql like `'D:\abc.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Rename it to cmd file, that may alter its behavior. And - what exactly is inside your batch?

Comment: same problem with cmd file .file contains `echo msgbox "Sorry Backup Failed!" > "%temp%\popup.vbs"
wscript.exe "%temp%\popup.vbs"`

Comment: You cannot use interactive commands (like vbs `msgbox`) from cmd files - SQL server execution context is not able to communicate with desktop. You better create command file, able to backup database (using `sqlcmd` or similar) and process results of sqlcmd command to display message box.

Answer (score 0):

Put the path inside ""

EXEC master..xp_CMDShell '"D:\test.bat"'

Run your script from ssms in admin mode, place your .bat file in other than C drive.

Comment: I did this.But Query doesn't stop execution